# Project Explorer in Eclipse is not shown

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to connect Java with Oracle 11g, while trying I have closed the Project Explorer in my Eclipse IDE. Now in my Eclipse IDE instead of the Project Explorer, only the Data Source Explorer is there. How could I restore my Project Explorer back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 'Window' menu choose 'Show View'. 'Project Explorer' should be in the pop-up list.

If it is not in the main list click 'Other...' and look in the 'General' section in the dialog that appears.

Comment: I found the "Project Explorer" in "Window -> Show View -> Others -> General -> Project Explorer"